# Async using of gRPC

Tags: c++, client-server, grpc

Does gRPC support the following scheme of communication between server and client?
1. Client connects to the server and calls some method like waitMessages. Then client is just waiting for some messages from the server.
2. From time to time the server sends messages to the client. For example, some method of the client is called.
3. The client disconnects from the server

I don't like to implement this scheme via polling the server. I would like to call server method one time and just wait for messages.

Answer (score 0):

`gRPC` does support partial responses or streaming. As stated on the `gRPC` [concepts page](https://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts/) (In the "*Server streaming RPC*" section):

> A server-streaming RPC is similar to our simple example, except the
>   server sends back a stream of responses after getting the client’s
>   request message. After sending back all its responses, the server’s
>   status details (status code and optional status message) and optional
>   trailing metadata are sent back to complete on the server side. The
>   client completes once it has all the server’s responses.

For completeness, `gRPC` also supports client streaming as well as bi-directional streaming.